# SQL Server 2012 mdf& ldf file is missing when power shut down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have used SQL Server 2012. System suddenly got stuck, so I restarted my system.

When I open the SQL Server then I can't see any  databases. Using `.mdf` and `.ldf` files, I have restored my databases.

But two `.mdf` & `.ldf` files are missing. File can't see any disk. How to recover the database? And also I don't have recent backup for that database.

```
dbcc checkdb
```

Comment: "and also i dont have recent backup for that database" - well, you should've had one. **no backup, no mercy**. also: this is not actually a coding question of any sorts. you should rather check on server fault.

Comment: "File can't see any disk" what does that mean? That the disk doesn't appear at all? That your disk just died? Why do you expect *SQL Server* fo resurrect a dead disk?

Comment: How do you expect to recover a database for which you have no backup, and whose disk died?

Comment: Finaly, neither SQL Server nor Windows "suddenly gets stuck". No OS or database can recover from a bad disk, which is why you *must* have backups. *Maybe* you could recover corrupted files from the bad disk if you used diagnostic and recovery utilities immediatelly, but it seems like you overwrote the disk with database backups